# Impresion con Socket en C#

Tags: c#, socket

Que tal compañeros buen día estoy haciendo un socket en C# para conectar con una impresora, este es el código que llevo hasta ahora,ya se conecta con la impresora y se imprime el mensaje, el problema es que se queda en la cola de impresión y no sale hasta que se manda otro documento
¿Como puedo hacer para que se mande en cuanto presiono el botón?

Lo segundo es que el programa se queda en la linea de //recibimos la respuesta de ahí ya no pasa, no manda error ni muestra nada, pero como ya mencione manda el documento a la cola de impresión

Gracias

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Impresion_etiquetas
{
    class Socket_p_imprimir
    {
        public void Socket_conectar() 
        {
            
            string mensaje = "Esta es una prueba del socket no1";
            Byte[] SendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mensaje);
            Byte[] RecvBytes = new byte[255];
            int bytes;
            string respuesta;

            IPAddress direc = Dns.GetHostEntry("Ip_impresora").AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint Ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("Ip_impresora"), puerto impresora);
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            

            try
            {

                socket.Connect(Ep);
                socket.Send(SendBytes, SendBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);//enviamos el msj
                bytes = socket.Receive(RecvBytes, RecvBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);//recibimos la respuesta
                respuesta = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(RecvBytes,0,bytes);
                while (bytes>0)
                {
                    bytes = socket.Receive(RecvBytes,RecvBytes.Length,SocketFlags.None);
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Hecho");
                
            }
            catch(Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Se produjo el sig. error: " + error);
          
            }
        }               
    }
   }
```

Comment: Creo que se le queda en `bytes = socket.Receive(RecvBytes, RecvBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None)` porque lo obliga a esperar por 256 bytes (que es el tamaño de `RecvBytes`) si la respuesta es mas corta, ese puede ser el problema. Intente con `socket.Available` en el tercer parametro de socket.Receive, así : `socket.Receive(RecvBytes, socket.Available, SocketFlags.None)`. La pregunta es antigua, no tengo impresora de red para probar el escenario, por lo que solo puedo contestar por comentario